# How to access all libraries when use find_package(<package_name>)

Tags: cmake

I `install` multiple libraries and `export` with the same names(inside one component). like bellow

```
install(
     TARGETS sip
     EXPORT voip-protocols-config)

install(
     TARGETS rtp
     EXPORT voip-protocols-config)

install(
     EXPORT voip-protocols-config
     NAMESPACE voip)
```

In the App side use `find_package(voip REQUIRED COMPONENTS voip-protocols)` and then access to these libs but have a way to use some symbols like `*` or [Cmake Generator Expression](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.23/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html?highlight=expression#target-dependent-queries) to list all libs inside the components?

With this approach, the details of the library side can be hidden in the program and for linking libs to app same as bellow:

```
find_package(voip REQUIRED COMPONENTS voip-protocols)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} voip::*)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When export targets (with `install(TARGETS .. EXPORT)`) CMake doesn't create additional "useful" targets. Instead, you (as a project's developer) are free to add such targets explicitly.

**First approach** is to create additional INTERFACE target in the project's `CMakeLists.txt` and install it too:

```
# Create "all" library
add_library(voip INTERFACE)
# Link the library with those ones, which you want to represent.
target_link_libraries(voip INTERFACE sip rtp <list other targets here>)
# Install library, so it will be accessible to the user of the package
# via name voip::voip.
install(TARGETS voip
  EXPORT voip-protocols-config)
```

**The second approach** would to add additional INTERFACE IMPORTED target to the he **project config script**.

It should be noted, that intended way for provide a config script is to write it **manualy** (or write its template and use `configure_package_config_file`). As for scripts *generated* by CMake with `install(EXPORT)`, these files could be included into the handwritten file. CMake describes that process in [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#creating-packages).

`voip-protocols-config.cmake`:

```
# Assume that install(EXPORT) creates file `voip-targets.cmake`
include (${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/voip-targets.cmake)

# Create "all" library
add_library(voip::voip INTERFACE IMPORTED)
# Link the library with those ones, which you want to represent.
target_link_libraries(voip INTERFACE voip::sip voip::rtp <list other targets here>)
```

---

Note, that CMake doesn't automatically select libraries according to COMPONENTS parameter for `find_package`. It is a project's developer who should process that parameter in the package config script. CMake documentation provides example of such processing.